# Google docs iframe not working on mobile devices

Tags: html, iframe, mobile, google-docs

I hope someone can help.  I am trying to embed an editable google doc into an iFrame, I am currently using

```
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/document/d/1bYwsERISJ8-jnn-tgDiMwkQEop1YvP41JZqhUQmYbHc/edit?widget=false&chrome=false&amp;headers=false&gridlines=false&embedded=true" width='1000' height='800' seamless="seamless" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

which is a shared test document.  This works fine on my windows desktop but does not work on any mobile devices e.g. Android phone, iPad.

Any ideas why or what I could be doing wrong?

Update 1
Perhaps having a URL with test will may be helpful http://google-test.itproz.co.uk

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this is a known issue with no resolution from Google: https://productforums.google.com/forum/?hl=ta#!topic/docs/WPMBrNIcLWU

I'm troubleshooting the same issue on another site and if I find out anything, I'll post here.